# Intellij: jboss-ejb3.xml entry keeps disappearing from ${PROJECT_DIR}/.idea/artifacts/XXX_war_exploded.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, java-ee-6

Why is it that although I've

1. set the proper path to the JBoss EJB deployment descriptor in my project's EJB facet
2. added `jboss-ejb3.xml` to Intellij's artifact Patrac-web:war exploded's <output root>/WEB-INF

that any time I make the simplest change to pom.xml Intellij removes the following entry from `${PROJECT_DIR}/.idea/artifacts/Patrac_web_war_exploded.xml`:

```
<element id="file-copy" path="$PROJECT_DIR$/Patrac-ejb/src/main/resources/META-INF/jboss-ejb3.xml" />
```

and, as a result, `jboss-ejb3.xml` does not get copied to the target directory?

It's as though each time I make a change to `pom.xml` Intellij "reloads" the deployment configuration using the POM to override what settings I make within the IDE.  Perhaps because I have no entry in my `pom.xml` for copying `jboss-ejb3.xml` from source directory to target directory the settings I make in Intellij IDE keep disappearing whenever Intellij "reloads."  Pure conjecture on my part, but this is what seems to be happening.

If so, what change do I need to make to `pom.xml` in order to make this stop happening?

Comment: It looks like a [known limitation](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91222) and your description of how it works is perfectly valid.

Comment: Tried several times to log into youtrack.jetbrains.com in order to add a comment to [IDEA-91222](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91222) without success.  Tried both open ID as well as known working login credentials, only to get redirected to login page without any error message/instructions.

Comment: Is the descriptor copied to the target folder when you build the project by Maven? If so how pom.xml is configured to do that? If the descriptor is located under a resources directory it should be copied to the target directory when the project is built by IDEA without any additional configuration.

Comment: No, when I build via Maven jboss-ejb3.xml does not get copied into WEB-INF.  It is when I make the simplest change to the POM (even adding a space character!) that IDEA loses the configuration and stops copying the descriptor.  It's as though IDEA is trying to match its configuration to that of the POM.  Then I have to go back into IDEA and reconfigure it to copy the descriptor.  Very frustrating indeed.

Comment: Shouldn't Maven be automatically discovering jboss-ejb3.xml in `F:\workarea\Patrac\Patrac-ejb\src\main\resources\META-INF` and copying it to the target directory?  Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Do you need to copy that descriptor to META-INF or WEB-INF directory? Ejb descriptors should be placed under META-INF directory. If you need to place a descriptor to WEB-INF directory its file should be located under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder.

Comment: The application is deployed as a WAR, with the EJBs in WEB-INF/lib/Patrac-ejb.jar.  Within the EJB JAR exists META-INF/jboss-ejb3.xml but there are deployment errors unless the deployment descriptor is also copied into WEB-INF.  I explicitly tell Intellij to copy the deployment descriptor into WEB-INF and everything works fine until I make the slightest change to my POM, in which case Intellij loses the configuration and I have to start all over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a project is (re)imported from Maven IDEA configures it such way that when you invoke 'Build' from IDEA it produces the same result as Maven's 'package' goal. If you need to copy jboss-ejb3.xml to WEB-INF just put it under 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF' directory and it will be copied by Maven and so do IDEA.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this.  I was aware that IDEA build/deploy configuration was following the Maven configuration because changes I've made in the past to my POMs affected IDEA (sometimes adversely, but the fault was always mine, I made the mistakes in my POMs!).  Your questions and suggestions caused me to take another look at my WAR POM and change the configuration in the POM in order to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to Nik's solution that I tried because I wanted to leave `jboss-ejb3.xml` in META-INF.  [Taking a look at the maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html), which shows how to treat `jboss-ejb3.xml` as a web resource and copy it into WEB-INF, I added the following to the maven-war-plugin configuration and the problem was resolved.  Well, kinda sorta.  But not really.

```
<webResources>
    <resource>
        <directory>../Patrac-ejb/src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>jboss-ejb3.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
    </resource>
</webResources>
```

Although doing it this way eliminated the need to fiddle around with IDEA facet configuration settings (because Maven was configured to copy the file, not IDEA), a new problem was introduced: two copies of `jboss-ejb3.xml` appeared in the WAR, one in WEB-INF and the other inside the EJB JAR (in META-INF).  Although there were no apparent consequences (the application ran just fine) I preferred not to have a duplicate copy of the descriptor located inside the EJB JAR.

Using the [Maven EJB plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/ejb-mojo.html), I tried to add an exclusion to my maven-ejb-plugin configuration e.g.

```
<configuration>
    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/jboss-ejb3.xml</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>
```

This should have prevented the duplicate copy of `jboss-ejb3.xml` from appearing in the EJB JAR META-INF but it didn't work for me, and after fruitlessly googling various variations of "maven-ejb-plugin excludes not working properly" I gave up.

If I could have gotten the excludes to work then I would have preferred this solution over moving `jboss-ejb3.xml` into src/main/webapp/WEB-INF because although this solution is slightly more complex (it requires additional Maven configuration settings in two POMs), the EJB-related descriptor would remain in the EJB module.

I've decided to go with Nik's solution until I can resolve the excludes problem.